# flutter doctor not able to run on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to run flutter doctor but when I do I get the following error:

Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

I have rebooted my pc to see if I could release any files that are being used but I still get the error. I have re-installed Android Studio and still get the error.

I have looked for solutions but have not been able to find any.

Have any of you had this same issue?

Comment: I had the same issue and running vscode as administrator solved my problem, try the same with android studio.